# Reading a URL as input applying some changes and then passing it on to open another website

Tags: java, php, python, html, jsp

So this is my final year project where we are sending an SMS through an Arduino. The SMS contains a URL with Lattitude and Longitude. I want to read these values of Lattitude and Longitude apply some changes and then pass it on to open another website or an embedded Google Map. 
Basically convert https://www.example.com/E:07700.44412-N:2906.37022 to https://www.google.co.in/maps/@07700.44412,2906.37022

The values of the Lattitude and Longitude will vary as per the location that is detected by the Arduino.

Comment: Cool. Let us know if you have any issues. If that happens, be sure to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking though.

Comment: A heads up; tag spamming is frowned upon. If you haven't even decided on a language to do something in, the question will automatically be counted as "too broad". SO is for questions about _specific_ issues with your _existing_ code.

Comment: Cool, make sure to update your post when your project is completed. Share your experience with StackOverFlow users

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP has some friends here that keep up voting the question. That doesn't make in on-topic though.

Comment: You missed **JS**, **Java-ee**, **JME**, **mysql** and **Haskell** tags.

Comment: Worth visiting: **[What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)**

Comment: @AniketSahrawat - You forgot about .NET, Go, Rust, Lisp, LOL Code, C64 basic, Delpi and Assembler.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Even you forgot Swift, C++, Ruby, C#, Elixir, Scala and R. :D

Comment: @AniketSahrawat - And you forgot AMOS, ASP 2.0, Pascal, M, LOL Code and.... ok... I'll stop now :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Okay, you won     